# cURL request returns different data

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing a simple cURL request using PHP requests curl library however when I look at the output it's different than the value on the page through a browser, why is this?

```
$headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
$options = array('auth' => array('user', 'pass'));
$request = Requests::get('somepage.php', $headers, $options);

var_dump($request->status_code);
// int(200)

var_dump($request->headers['content-type']);
// string(31) "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

### output

```
var_dump($request->body);
<img src="img/collection_id/a49ddalf31.png" class="cars">
```

---

and yet when I visit the page on my browser the image is:

```
<img src="img/collection_id/b393alldf.png" class="cars">
```

**Is there a way to retrieve the correct image?**

Comment: It could be due to caching on their part, or they could be serving different images based on the user agent or a number of other factors. It would be easier to give a definitive answer if you would provide the URL you're `curl`ing.

Comment: the output depends on what logic is behind the page you are trying to access. if the output changes on different requests then maybe an internal logic is switching the output based on specific  criteria (user_agent etc...)

Comment: The output could possibly be changing due to your cookies? You could try to clear your cookies, and revisit the page. In the past, I have found that redirects can also show different output in a browser than in a normal get request, this can be configured via `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r($request)`
If you don't get anything, you should check the parameters the request expects.